# Cant write data in database using codeigniter

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I have a controller, model and view file. I am trying to write data to database using the form on view file. I am trying to validate the post data using a mix of Codeigniter Validation library and some methods defined by. This validation is being done in Controller. Then I am trying to pass data array to the model. In the model I am trying to read the data array and build a query to insert data in database.

The problem is that no data is being written in the database.
I dont see any visible errors in the browser. I have been stuck on this for some time now. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Controller**

```
function add_customer() {

    $this->load->model('Customer_Model');
    $data['title'] = "Add New Customer";


    $this->load->view('templates/header' , $data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/add_customer' , $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer' , $data);

    if($this->input->post())
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|customer_email_exists');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|customer_mobile_exists');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Address', 'trim|required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()){
              $customer_data = array(
                        'name' => $this->validation->name,
                        'email' => $this->validation->email,
                        'mobile' => $this->validation->mobile,
                        'address' => $this->validation->address
                        );
                $this->Customer_Model->add_customer($customer_data);
            }else{

            }
    }
}
public function customer_email_exists($email) {
    $this->load->model('Customer_Model');   
    if(!$this->Customer_Model->email_exists($email)){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_exists', 'Email already registered, try another one.');
            return false;
        }
    }
public function customer_mobile_exists($mobile) {
    $this->load->model('Customer_Model');   
    if(!$this->Customer_Model->mobile_exists($mobile)){
            return true;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_exists', 'Email already registered, try another one.');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

**Model**

```
class Customer_Model extends CI_Model{
function add_customer($customer_data)
{

    $data = array(
        'id'=>'',
        'name'=>$customer_data["name"],
        'email'=>$customer_data["email"],
        'mobile'=>$customer_data["mobile"],
        'address'=>$customer_data["address"]
    );
    $this->db->insert('customer',$data);
    $this->db->query($query);
}
public function email_exists($email) {
        $this->db->where("email = '$email' AND email != ''");
        $query = $this->db->get('customer');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function mobile_exists($mobile) {
        $this->db->where('mobile',$mobile);
        $query = $this->db->get('customer');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }}
```

**View**

```
<section class="versir-section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
            <form method="post">
                <table width="600" border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="230">Customer Name</td>
                    <td width="329"><input type="text" name="name"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Customer Email </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Customer Mobile </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="mobile"/></td>
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>Customer Address </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="address"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save Data"/></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you output `$customer_data` in your controller prior to going to the model - is there any data within it?

Comment: Array has all the data

Comment: Ok - next step is rather than do `$this->db->insert('customer',$data);` do `$this->db->get_compiled_insert('customer',$data);` instead. Output it and then run the query in the database directly and see what happens.

Comment: On it. Running query directly in database

Comment: So running the query directly works as expected with the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm! I think in this code part you should get post data from input, not from validation

```
if ($this->form_validation->run()){
  $customer_data = array(
      'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
      'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
      'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
      'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
  );
  $this->Customer_Model->add_customer($customer_data);
}else{

}
```

Comment: Tried no effect

Comment: Do you fall into the method of add_customer to the Customer_Model with all the data?  And the array keys match the name of the columns in the table?

Comment: Let me check this again

Comment: If the id field is autoincrementing, you should not pass it to insert